# button text for editing

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML button where I would like the user to edit the text on it and limit it to 5 digits and digits only when the button is pressed. If the users enters something other then digits, cancel the editing and return to the original number.

I wrote the following HTML for the button:

```
<button id='altitudeBtn' type='button' class='btn btn-default' contenteditable="true" onkeypress="validateNumber()" onclick="altBtnPressed()">
```

JS:

```
function altBtnPressed(){
    previousAltitude = document.getElementById('altitudeBtn').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('altitudeBtn').innerHTML = '';
    altBtnPressedBool = true;
}

function validateNumber(event) {
    if(altBtnPressedBool){
        var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;
        if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46) {
            return;
        } else if ( key < 48 || key > 57 ) {
            //return false;
            document.getElementById('altitudeBtn').innerHTML = previousAltitude;
        } else {
            //code for correct input;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the Trick

```
} else {
    //code for correct input;
    if(document.getElementById('altitudeBtn').innerHTML.Length <= 4) {
        document.getElementById('altitudeBtn').innerHTML =
        document.getElementById('altitudeBtn').innerHTML + String.fromCharCode(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but It doesn't limit the number of char that can be written and if I write a wrong character it still shows up on my button?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

```
function validateNumber(event) {
if(altBtnPressedBool){
    var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;
    if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46) {
        return true;
    } else if ( key < 48 || key > 57 ) {
        return false;
        //document.getElementById('altitudeBtn').innerHTML = previousAltitude;
    } else {
        return (document.getElementById('altitudeBtn').innerHTML.length <= 4);
    }
}
```

}